# How to access Stringproperty value from other class in KIVYMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

so im making app where you can add folders with some words and then play some card games in order to learn these words.

Code is quite long so ill try explain where my problem is.

Lets say i have this file with  a user , folder name(Food) and words :

```
{
    "user1": {
        "food": {
            "mleko": "milk",
            "jajko": "egg",
            "jablko": "apple",         Thats small part of the file just to show how it looks
            "zaba": "frog"
           }
        }
 }
```

Thats the Screen where id like to add automatically on enter Custom widgets

```
<EditFolder>:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols:1
        id:editfolder
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Folders"
            elevation:2
            right_action_items:[['plus', lambda x:root.add()]]
            left_action_items:[['arrow-left', lambda x: root.back()]]
        MDBoxLayout:
            #size_hint:1,.85   
            MDScrollViewRefreshLayout:
                id:refresh_layout
                refresh_callback: root.refresh_callback
                root_layout: root
                size_hint:1,1
                GridLayout:
                    id:box
                    cols:2
                    spacing:15,15                  <<<<< Here i add custom widgets
                    padding:15,15
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height: self.minimum_height
```

My custom widgets looks like this

```
<Cardy>:   
    size_hint:.4,None
    height:100
    elevation: 5
    md_bg_color:210/255, 210/255, 210/255,1
    on_release:
        #root.get_word()          << tried to get a text value with this
        root.word_list()           <<< redirects me to new screen by pressing that Card widget
    MDFloatLayout:           
        MDLabel:
            text:root.card_name
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
```

And now thats my py part of the code

```
class Cardy(MDCard):
    card_name = StringProperty()

    def word_list(self):
        app.root.current= 'edit_words'      << redirects me to new screen

      


class EditFolder(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self):

        user = self.manager.get_screen('login_screen').ids.username.text
        with open('data.json',encoding='utf8') as file:
            words = json.load(file)
            self.list = [i for i in words[user]]
            for i in self.list:
                self.ids.box.add_widget(Cardy(card_name= str(i)))
```

So as you can see i add as many Custom widgets(Card) as many folders i have in my file. In other part of the app you can add/remove folders and words inside that why i need to do this dynamically.

[image]

I did it, created dynamically widgets(Card with a label inside) and named them by a folder name.
Now my problem is that i want to make that when u press on each card it will redirect me to new screen with also dynamically created widget containing al the words that where inside that folder.

Thats also a aprt i did myself. I made it but the PROBLEM HERE IS that it works only if i define folder name by myself.

```
def on_pre_enter(self):
    with open('data.json',encoding='utf8') as file:
        words = json.load(file)
        user = self.manager.get_screen('login_screen').ids.username.text    <<<Get the username from other screen
        folder = Cardy.card_name  <<<< Here id like to somehow get automatically folder name
        self.result = [key for key in words[user]['food'].items()]       <<< i define folder name by myself
        for i in self.result:
            self.ids.box.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon='translate',
                    content=Content(),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                        text=i[0],
                        secondary_text=i[1],
                    )
                )
            )
```

Id like to access Custom widget Label text whenever i press on specific card. So if i press on FOOD Card it will tell my func from another class what folder to open and created widgets in new screen

If i use self.card_game inside my custom widget class i get the labels text but then i dont know how to pass it to another class so i can use it as arg inside another func

I hope i kind of made it clear, sorry for messy post. Any help would be appreciated